# How do I make so that the UV Grid is not stretched?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I have 2 objects, 1 plane and 1 rectangle (long cube). I’ve unwrap the 2 (using Smart UV Project) and then created materials (generated type: Empty) for them and tried texture painting them using the same texture. The texture painting for the plane looks ok but for the rectangle, its blurry and seems stretched out.

I tried creating a new material for the rectangle this time using a UV Grid and found out that the grids are stretched:

[image]

It seems to me this is the thing that’s causing the blurriness. What do I need to do so that the UV Grid isn’t stretched? The only thing I was able to do is create a material with dimensions 2048x16384 then after that the UV Grid is not stretched anymore:

[image]

But the problem with this is when I save the image it is very large (and also its slowing my computer when painting).

**EDIT:**

Added some images as requested:

UV for plane
[image]

UV for rectangle
[image]

Comment: Can you share an image of how it looks in the UV Editor?

Comment: Ok, I've added them in the question.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/LYS6DBF/d60UA.jpg

Try scale it down horizontally.

Comment: The first thing I suggest is to Apply Scale to the object that seems to deform prior to unwrapping.